# Pass glm predictors from a list

Tags: r, plyr

I have a large set of model specifications to test, which share a  dv but have unique IVs. In the following example

```
foo <- data.frame(dv  = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace=T),
                  x1 = runif(100),
                  x2 = runif(100))
```

I want the first model to only include x1, the second x2, the third both, and the fourth their interaction. So I thought a sensible way would be to build a list of formula statements:

```
bar <- list("x1",
            "x2", 
            "x1+x2",
            "x1*x2")
```

which I would then use in a `llply` call from the `plyr` package to obtain a list of model objects.

```
require(plyr)
res <- llply(bar, function(i) glm(dv ~ i, data = foo, family = binomial()))
```

Unfortunately I'm told

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = dv ~ i, data = foo, drop.unused.levels = TRUE):variable lengths differ (found for 'i')
```

Obviously I'm mixing up something fundamental--do I need to manipulate the original foo list in some fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `dv ~ i` isn't a formula. `i` is (inside the anonymous function) simply a symbol that represents a variable containing a character value.

Try this:

```
bar <- list("dv~x1",
            "dv~x2", 
            "dv~x1+x2",
            "dv~x1*x2")

res <- llply(bar, function(i) glm(i, data = foo, family = binomial()))
```

But setting statistical issues aside, it might possibly be easier to use something like `?step` or `?stepAIC` in the **MASS** package for tasks similar to this?

Comment: brilliant, thanks joran. 

I appreciate your suggestion about `MASS`, however, in this case, I have a specific set of model specifications in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with how you are specifying the formula, since inside the function i is a variable. This would work:

```
glm(paste("dv ~", i), data = foo, family = binomial())
```

Comment: this works for any formula, I tried it for rpart to feed in my selected features.